# SP2010: How to display a lookup column in a .aspx displayform

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xpath, lookup, sharepoint-designer

- I have the two Lists Articles(A) and Serial Inspections(S).
- The Article-List has columns: Article-#, Name, DescriptionDE, DescriptionEN, somemore...
- The Serial Inspections: Inspection-#, Inspector, Values and a lookup column which refers to the Article-#.
- In Addition to that in SP2010 you can choose some more Columns which are Displayed in the Serial Inspections list which are then Named like: Article-#:Name.
- Now i took the Sharepoint Designer2010 and made myself a Printable Form of a single listitem in Serial Inspections. I basically took the displayform.aspx and made changes. Accessing it by link /printform.aspx?ID=1234 to show the entry with ID 1234.
- I can select the Lookup Column Article-# itself. Now its important for me to show the additional lookup column Article-#:Name but i cant choose it from the x-path list.

---

> Good approach:
>   I got the HiddenID of the Lookup Column Artikel-#: "Artikel_x002d_*x0023*" and the Additional Lookup Column Artikel-#:Name 's ID is: "Artikel_x002d_*x0023*_x003a_Arti"
>   So i tried: `<xsl:value-of select="@Artikel_x002d__x0023__x003a_Arti" />`

Sadly that doesnt show anything... but the Artikel-# Column does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the column Article-# to the Serial Inspections, too and fill the value with a workflow when ever an Item changes.